# getJSON not working / phonegap.plist not found

Tags: javascript, xcode, api, cordova, getjson

I have recently downloaded XCode4.5.2 and PhoneGap2.3.0 and Cordova 2.3.0 to develop an iOS app. I was trying to use this function to get some data from the wikipedia API:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
   <html>
     <head>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova-2.3.0.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

        <script>
         function get_data(){

                var query = 'Ocean';
                var url = 'http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?callback=?&action=parse&format=json&page='+query+'&prop=text';
                alert(url);

                $.getJSON(url,function(response){
                          alert('Here!');
                          });

                       };


        </script>

        </head>
        <body>
        <input type="button" value="search" onclick="get_data()"   />
        </body>
   </html>
```

However, i cannot make this work. The alert(url) works fine but not the alert('Here!').
The problem seems to be on the getJSON function in PhoneGap.

I have read in some posts that the solution could be on "adding your domain to the ExternalHosts section of the phonegap.plist" or "putting the appropriate Access tags in the config.xml file". I cannot find the phonegap.plist file in this 2.3.0 version of Cordova (does it exist?!). Only the config.xml (which i have confirmed as having the `<access origin="*" />`).

Can somebody help me with this please?

Answer (score 0):

1. As i know, getJSON is a jQuery function, why don't you included jQuery's js file?
2. Where is the your function caller? if do you expect it to run on load, use

   $(function(){
      get_data();
   }

Comment: I have edited the code. Please see above the last modified html code. Any ideas why the alert('Here!') is not coming out?. Thank you.

Comment: try to to use regular ajax function with text, maybe your call response doesnt contain valid JSON content..

$.ajax({
  url: url,
  cache: false,
dataType:'text',
}).done(function( resp ) {
  alert(resp);
});